# Is there any news about the Lost Fleet books and spinoffs?

Tags: the-lost-fleet

I have read all the books in the [Lost Fleet series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41101-the-lost-fleet) and the Spinoffs [The Lost Stars](https://www.goodreads.com/series/88284) Series.

I'm curious if the author has ever said if he will be making more of these lovely things??
Can't find anything on [his page](http://www.jack-campbell.com/index.html) that I stumbled upon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spoke to my good friend Jack Campbell (AKA John Henry) by email. He would like to reassure you that he plans to crank out a whole bunch more Lost Fleet novels, stories and even a comic series.

> "... the answer
> is on my website (jack-campbell.com) and there's also stuff there about the
> upcoming Lost Fleet comic series.  Long story short, yes, Shattered Spear next
> May, then the First Stars trilogy (same universe, centuries earlier)"

---

And from his [website](http://jack-campbell.com/)

> I'll be writing a new trilogy set in the Lost Fleet The First Stars will be set centuries before the events in The Lost Fleet, showing the events, challenges, and people who led a bunch of fiercely independent star systems to first form the Alliance, as well as the first clashes between the Alliance and the expanding Syndicate Worlds.
>
> There is more of a frontier feel to this time, with star systems still being colonized and closer ties to the older star systems and Earth itself. But it's still the Lost Fleet universe, with all of the elements that have made that series stand out. More to follow!
>
> **The Lost Stars: Shattered Spear ([now available](https://titanbooks.com/the-lost-stars-shattered-spear-book-4-a-novel-in-the-lost-fleet-universe-7638/))**
>
> Book four of The Lost Stars will come out in May, 2016. Many issues will finally be resolved. Some of those in the story will not survive. Others will, at last, figure out the answers to questions they have long wrestled with.Shattered Spear marks an end and a beginning.
>
> **The Lost Fleet Comic Series ([now available](http://comicsalliance.com/jack-campbell-lost-fleet-titan/))**
>
> This is still in development and, hopefully, the first issue will come out in 2016. The Lost Fleet comic series will feature new stories I've written that take place outside the novels of The Lost Fleet and Beyond The Frontier. Some of the questions asked about what happened to certain characters may finally be answered.

---

The first book ([Vanguard](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31753882-vanguard)) in his new and now retitled "Genesis trilogy" has been released with more books in production. Unfortunately the author has suffered some eye problems over the previous year which has slowed him down somewhat.

> **I read on your website you are taking a break from The Lost Fleet and are writing a prequel trilogy called The First Stars. How has the writing been and when can we expect to see the first book?**
>
> *The writing has been complicated a bit by, among other things, a detached retina, but is now nearly done for the first novel (Vanguard).  It has been fun for me to explore The Lost Fleet universe in the period when humanity was exploding among the stars, settling many worlds and outrunning the old systems that had maintained law and order.  In a Wild West environment, the ancestors of some men and women familiar from The Lost Fleet along with others have to deal with a lot of unexpected challenges.  My understanding is that Vanguard should come out in June, 2017.*
>
> <sub><sup>[JACK CAMPBELL’S ‘THE LOST FLEET: CORSAIR’ FINDS HOME AT TITAN COMICS [EXCLUSIVE]](http://comicsalliance.com/jack-campbell-lost-fleet-titan/)</sup></sub>

Comment: I <3 you!! you have made me a happy camper!! :-)

Comment: @cherubel - My only concern is your happiness :-)

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the info! As much as I would want to know what challenges will Geary face, expansion of universe into the past sounds absolutely amazing!

Comment: @Alex I converted your 'answer' to a comment.  You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Valorum So After Leviathan and Shattered Spear he started writing a prequel series to describe the birth of the alliance ets... Is there going to be any more books about Black Jack and the alliance series? or Prez Iceni and her Midway empire? Both series were kinda left on a cliffhanger.